# WebRTC : Simulate ICE server error

Tags: webrtc

I am developing a small webrtc app, peers able to connect and conference, but I want to catch the situation where peer is not able to connect to ICE server or is getting no port for streaming media.

I am not sure what sort of error I would get in these situations, so, is there any way I can simulate these problems, or could someone tell me what would happen in the situation of ICE server failure or port inavailability.